# Compiling and Calling Code at Runtime

Tags: vb.net

The other day, I took up a little bit of a project: creating an IRC bot. Currently, it works (with a few bugs that I know about and am working towards fixing), but there is one feature that I would like to implement. External modules.

Basically, what I am wanting is to have the end user be able to write their own Sub and have that checked when a message arrives.

Each sub that is checked starts off something like this:

```
Sub sampleSub(message As String)
```

What calls that bit of code is (another) sub that is run through when a message arrives. In short, when a message arrives, the following code is executed:

```
sampleSub(message)
```

(where message = the incoming message to be processed)

Is there a way to check a folder (say, /modules) for all .vb files, compile said files to .dll, and add those to a list of subs above to be checked?

(If you don't understand what I'm meaning about the above code, see https://github.com/xeon927/IRCBot/blob/master/main.vb lines 213, and 337-348)

Comment: Sounds like a good way for people to infect computers. Maybe you can consider creating some kind of API for the external scripts

Comment: That was another thing that I was thinking of to do. Maybe an XML file with triggers along with responses to send. I haven't thought too much about that as a second option though.